# Coldfusion Post to a query to build a query

Tags: mysql, post, coldfusion

Good day all.

I want to build a dynamic query on the fly.
This is what I would like to do.

```
<cfform name="form1" method="post" action="mysql_fix.cfm">

<table width="450" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Code</td>
    <td>
    <textarea name="codetoinsert" rows="5" cols="80"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><cfinput type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<table>
</cfform>
```

And on my result

```
<cfset codeis = #replacenocase(FORM.codetoinsert,chr(34),#CHR(39)#,"All")#>
<cfset codeis = #replacenocase(codeis,"#CHR(39)##CHR(39)#",#CHR(39)#,"All")#>
<cfquery name="dodata" datasource="#datasrc#">
    #codeis#
</cfquery>
```

But i get this error. the error is in the double quotes.

i post this in the textarea

```
INSERT INTO payments
(description,amount,paytype,closed,customer,dateof,username,location,oldbalance,newbalance,invoiceno,closedtime,allocated,closeduser)
VALUES
('FOR Invoice No : 9960',0.00,'Account','Yes',7907,'2014/07/22 12:00:00','Ruby','2',3800.01,7600.02,9960,'2014/07/22 18:31:41','Yes','Ruby')
```

this is the error. its putting in ''

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOR Invoice No : 9960'',0.00,''Account'',''Yes'',7907,''2014/07/22 12:00:00'',''' at line 1
```

Comment: Have you tried dumping the result after every `codeis` statement? I don't think you are doing it right. The Posted query in text area has a `single quote` and then `replacenocase(FORM.codetoinsert,chr(34),#CHR(39)#,"All")` is replacing `double quotes` (which are not there) with the `single quotes`

Comment: Allowing users to directly enter ad-hoc SQL queries like this is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sure hope that code is not exposed to the public: it's a recipe for disaster.

But, anyway, when you have DB issues, the first thing to do is to look at the SQL being sent to the DB. Not the SQL in your `<cfquery>` tag (on in your case, the `<textarea>`, but the SQL that CF is actually sending to the DB driver. It's displayed in the debug output.

If you checked that, you'll more than likely see that CF is escaping all the single quotes in your SQL statement. This is by design (one of questionable merit, IMO, but still).

To make CF not do that, wrap your SQL statement with `preserveSingleQuotes()`.

As side notes:

- you don't need the `#` around expressions unless they're within
  strings or somehow otherwise confuseable as being literals ("[When to
  use pound-signs](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/when-to-use-pound-signs.html)")
- you shouldn't be passing data values hardcoded in your SQL string,
  you should be passing them as parameters. It might not be such a
  problem if this is for add-hoc query execution, but as a general rule
  ("[What one can and cannot do with `<cfqueryparam>`](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2012/07/what-one-can-and-cannot-do-with.html)")

Comment: Thanks did exactly what i wanted. preserveSingleQuotes(). this is not publicaly available. that would be really stupid. im am aware of cfquery peram but not worried about this page